# user login and its profile

Tags: users

i want login, logout and view profile functionality.
i am currently able to login the user and redirect them to home page of website. i want to show loggedin users name on menu and a logout link.
for getting username of currently logged user i tried this:http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user
but not able to get the username.
for login/logout link i used this code in functions.php

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_login_logout_link', 10, 2);
function add_login_logout_link($items, $args) {
    ob_start();
    wp_loginout('index.php');
    $loginoutlink = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    $items .= '<li>'.  $loginoutlink .'</li>';
    return $items;
 }
```

Comment: The returned value from `wp_get_current_user` is an object. How are you retrieving username? Please show us proper code.

Comment: I setup whole site on another server and its working there, i think the problem is in server.

Answer (score 1):

I've just done something like this and it's fairly simple

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_login_logout_link', 10, 2);
function add_login_logout_link($items, $args) {
    //check if user is logged in, and add user name to menu 
    if (is_user_logged_in()){
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        $items .= '<li>' . $user->display_name . '</li>';

    }
    //add login/logout link to menu
    $items .= '<li>'.  wp_loginout(get_permalink(),false) .'</li>';
    return $items;
 }
```